How do I generate new text when clicking a button in html/javascript?
I am trying to create a button where every time you click, a new sentence generates from a list. What I have now is only generating a new sentence when I refresh the page and I'm not sure what to try. I only started learning yesterday so be nice to me please.
Here is what I have so far.
<div>
    <button onclick="button" id="myButton">Hit me.</button>
    <p id="randomQuote"> </p>
</div>

<script>

    var quote = ["S1","S2","S3","S4",  ];

    var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
    document.getElementById("randomQuote").innerHTML = quote[randomQuote];

</script> 


Avoid the use of HTML disseminated inline on* JS attribute handlers. Use rather addEventListener from your JS tag or file instead.

learn about functions (in JS or any other programming language if you will) and how to instantiate and call them. Learn about JavaScript Events handling. Hard to grasp with the arguments and all the this mess, but once you get it you're basically good to go with advanced patterns concepts.

You should provide a function call (onclick's value should be a JS expression) in onclick's value:


<div>
    <button onclick="onButtonClick()" id="myButton">Hit me.</button>
    <p id="randomQuote"> </p>
</div>

<script>

    var quote = ["S1","S2","S3","S4",  ];

    function onButtonClick() {
      var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
      document.getElementById("randomQuote").innerHTML = quote[randomQuote];
    }

</script> 



But a recommended way is to use addEventListener:


<div>
    <button id="myButton">Hit me.</button>
    <p id="randomQuote"> </p>
</div>

<script>

    var quote = ["S1","S2","S3","S4",  ];

    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
      document.getElementById("randomQuote").innerHTML = quote[randomQuote];
    });

</script> 



Also I would recommend to learn the modern JS from the beginning: const/let instead of var, arrow functions, etc.

Use an event listener rather than an onclick attribute, then call your callback funtion in your event listener when you click the button.
Also you placed the button element in the HTML onclick call within your HTML. This answer here may also help out.


const quote = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"];

const btn = document.getElementById('myButton');

const getQuote = () => {
  let randomItem = quote[Math.floor(Math.random()*quote.length)];
  document.getElementById("randomQuote").textContent = randomItem;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', getQuote);
<div>
  <button type="button" id="myButton">Hit me.</button>
  <p id="randomQuote"> </p>
</div>



